# Has there ever been a model (neuro-physical) proposed for the human unconscious brain?

Tags: human-like

**Has there ever been a model (neuro-physical) proposed for the human unconscious brain**?

---

I tried reading on [unconscious mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unconscious_mind) but couldn't find anything which answers the question.

---

Is there any literature related to it?

Comment: Welcome to AI.  This is a good question!  One of [Hubert Dreyfus's critiques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubert_Dreyfus%27s_views_on_artificial_intelligence) is *"...that human intelligence and expertise depend primarily on unconscious instincts rather than conscious symbolic manipulation, and that these unconscious skills could never be captured in formal rules."*

Comment: @DukeZhou Thank you for your response :)
Though it didn't help much, but, "still something is better than nothing".

Comment: It may be that AI is not sufficiently advanced to be regarded as having consciousness, or even minds, and so unconscious mechanisms aren't yet relevant, except from a philosophical perspective.

Comment: please update your question for further clarification

Answer (score 1):

The Unconscious in psychology is related to many aspects of **behavior**, but many levels of this exist, including low levels (simple tasks) like walking, eating, breathing etc.  This has been investigated in animal world, for example [muscular memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscle_memory), the [insect brain model](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature23455), and [Nonlinear System Control Using Neural Networks](https://www.uni-obuda.hu/journal/Zilkova_Timko_Girovsky_8.pdf) . Many of these are related to body control.

See also: [nested hierarchies of circular emotional control and cognitive regulation for “bottom-up” influences and “top-down” regulations](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5573739/figure/F1/)

Comment: Can you provide a note on the distinction between autonomic processes and subconscious psychological processes?  (The links you provide are good, particularly *Nonlinear System Control Using Neural
Networks* but I feel like this answer would benefit from a little more granularity.)  PS-Welcome to AI!

Comment: [link] (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5573739/figure/F1/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Though it's not satisfactory, still gives something to ponder upon.